# Triggering react-native events from widget - android

Tags: javascript, android, events, react-native, native

I've made an app using react-native, however I need to trigger a react event from an android widget. This is currently my setup:

```
public class IsHetAlBierTijdWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.is_het_al_bier_tijd_widget);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
            sendEventToReactApp(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    public void sendEventToReactApp(Context context) {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
        ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext = new ReactApplicationContext(context);
        MSREventBridgeModule msrEventBridgeModule = new MSREventBridgeModule(reactApplicationContext);
        msrEventBridgeModule.emitEvent("Widget_Update",event);
    }
}
```

react code:

```
class Home extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.onWidgetUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    onWidgetUpdate(){
        console.log("widget update...");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchBierTijd()
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('Widget_Update', this.onWidgetUpdate);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('Widget_Update', this.onWidgetUpdate);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Countdown
                    style={{marginTop: 80}} fontSize="40"
                    isBiertijd={this.props.isBierTijd}
                    timeLeft={this.props.timeLeft}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToPros = state => ({
    fetching: state.bierTijd.fetching,
    isBierTijd: state.bierTijd.isBierTijd,
    nextBierTijd: state.bierTijd.next,
    timeLeft: moment(state.bierTijd.next).diff(moment())
})


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({...bierTijdActions,}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToPros, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Is it possible to do this, or does the event need to be triggered from the main activity? a good explanation of communication from native to react native would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is definitely possible and you can find a guide here:

#### [React Native Android Widget Proof of Concept](https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-android-widget-poc)

You must create a BroadcastReceiver (i.e. the WidgetProvider) and a HeadlessJS task to communicate both together. Maybe there are other approaches, but at least this one that works!

Comment: widgetTask.js doesn't seems to reflect changes after editing the file. Not sure why